# What is the standard procedure to design a Synchronous Machine?

Tags: design, generator, magnetics, magnetic-flux, synchronous-motor

I have Modelled an IPMSM based on the innovative idea i got. I have also decided on the rating of the machine, torque to be produced, Required Rated RPM, but after this i have so much doubt. whether should i hire someone to make a model in Ansys maxwell and Analyse it from there or should i have to calculated other parameters like dimension of the motor, resistance per phase, Inductance, grade of magnet to be used, grade of Copper to be used etc.
Experts in IPMSM design or just any electrical motor design. Teach me the Professional Workflow.

Comment: Do everything you can think of that can possibly go wrong and then see if doing everything works with your budget. Do a risk analysis.

Comment: that's how the industries do? @Andyaka

Comment: "The industries" start with an existing design and determine what they need change to meet different requirements. The question mentions "innovative idea." That implies you have an idea to improve something. You first analyze the thing that you want to improve and then apply your innovation to that design.

Comment: Sorry @CharlieCowie i forgot to mention it as "Inventive idea". And i request you to answer specifically like, what are the parameters will they assume and how will they proceed like, with simulation? or with calculating rest of the parameters and then simulating it. And it would be grateful if you could share me some examples!

Comment: @MohammedSiddique whether you use "inventive" or "innovative" here: makes absolutely no difference. They mean the same, essentially. And Charles' answer is on point: you do what you know to do, and see if it works, and before doing that, you make an estimate of whether the realistic outcome of what you're doing is sensible compared to the time and money you need to invest to try it. Simulation? Yes, if the improvement you try would benefit from that? Calculation? Of course, this is engineering, if you have a model of the system you're modifying, you'd use it...

Comment: Your question really is "how do I improve a complex system", and the answer to that is "you use engineering". I'm afraid your question is too broad.

Comment: Sorry @MarcusMüller i was trying to get answers specific and you answered one half thanks!. i have Invented an idea to create a motor but technically what assumption will i have to consider like power output, Rated RPM etc and what things should i have to find out using simulation software like Turns, Flux density, Grade of magnet etc...Be Technically specific in the answer... that's where i have the doubt in!

Comment: Standard procedure would be to start with requirements and proceed from there. Decide on a power level for example. As this is an innovative design, first study a standard device at your chosen power level. What does it cost? weigh? what materials does it use? what makes it so cheap (or expensive)? what limits its power output? Can your design do better, for less money? Or less weight? Or less expensive materials? Or with more efficiency? If the answer to these is NO, the next question is why bother?

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend that you validate your design yourself to begin with.

If your motor can be modeled in 2D, I would recommend that you download Finite Element Method Magnetics (https://www.femm.info/wiki/HomePage). This is a free magnetic solver that provides identical results to Ansys Maxwell (note, I have used both and I actually prefer FEMM). There are lots of useful tutorials showing off the various features. You can also link FEMM with MATLAB and utilize MATLAB's built in optimization tools, to improve your design.

Your design process might look something like this:
0. Have some requirements/ goals you want to achieve.

1. Start by configuring the outside dimensions of your device, such as length and outside radius.
2. Select Magnetic materials, conductive materials
3. Build initial geometry.
4. Analyze flux distributions, flux densities, and Inductance.
5. Modify geometry. Repeat step 4.
6. Determine number of turns, and wiring configuration.
7. Analyze torque/power using rated currents. Repeat step 4
8. Determine shaft diameter, pressfit tolerances.